# How to query data which is not unique up to a certain point?

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically the current conditions of the query are

```
WHERE data_payload_uri BETWEEN
'/organization/team/folder/2021'
AND
'/organization/team/folder/2022'
```

And this gets all data for the year of 2021.

A sample of the data_payload_uri data looks like this:

```
/organization/team/folder/20210101/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210102/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210102/orig_v1
/organization/team/folder/20210103/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210104/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig_v1
/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig_v2
```

What I would like to do is only query the rows where up until the last forward-slash, the row is NOT unique.

What this means, is I want to NOT query the rows which ONLY have one orig

```
/organization/team/folder/20210101/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210103/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210104/orig
```

but I DO want to query all the other rows

```
/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig_v1
/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig_v2
/organization/team/folder/20210102/orig
/organization/team/folder/20210102/orig_v1
```

What is the best way to do this? Pls let me know if anything is unclear and thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the analytic `COUNT` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT data_payload_uri) OVER (
           PARTITION BY SUBSTR(data_payload_uri, 1, INSTR(data_payload_uri, '/', -1))
         ) AS cnt
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  data_payload_uri >= '/organization/team/folder/2021'
  AND    data_payload_uri <  '/organization/team/folder/2022'
)
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, data_payload_uri) AS
SELECT 1, '/organization/team/folder/20210101/orig' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '/organization/team/folder/20210102/orig' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '/organization/team/folder/20210102/orig_v1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '/organization/team/folder/20210103/orig' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '/organization/team/folder/20210104/orig' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, '/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, '/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig_v1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, '/organization/team/folder/20210105/orig_v2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | DATA_PAYLOAD_URI | CNT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | /organization/team/folder/20210102/orig | 2 |
> | 3 | /organization/team/folder/20210102/orig_v1 | 2 |
> | 6 | /organization/team/folder/20210105/orig | 3 |
> | 7 | /organization/team/folder/20210105/orig_v1 | 3 |
> | 8 | /organization/team/folder/20210105/orig_v2 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=28cf61fe35e259a4801ac27003f00354)*

Comment: thank you so much. this is exactly what i needed, and helped me solve my problem and get a query running. extra thanks for including the db<>fiddle, it helped me customize the solution from the test-code here to the real code. thank you so much!